# How to fix Unresolved reference: setupWithViewPager

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement TableLayout on ViewPager but i can not use method setupWithViewPager because android studio says that it is unresolved reference.

This TableLayout and ViewPager should be implemented in fragment (AboutFragment.kt)

My ViewPager works perfectly fine without TabLayout, I mean i can swipe between fragments.

Does somebody have solution?

Here is my AboutFragment:

```
package hr.ferit.brunozoric.taskie.ui.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import hr.ferit.brunozoric.taskie.R
import hr.ferit.brunozoric.taskie.ui.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter
import hr.ferit.brunozoric.taskie.ui.fragments.base.BaseFragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_about.*



class AboutFragment: BaseFragment() {



    override fun getLayoutResourceId(): Int {
        return R.layout.fragment_about

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupPager()



    }

    private fun setupPager() {
        viewPager.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager!!)
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)  // I have error in this line :(

    }


    companion object{
        fun newIstance(): Fragment {
            return AboutFragment()
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my ViewPagerAdapter:

```
package hr.ferit.brunozoric.taskie.ui.adapters

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
import hr.ferit.brunozoric.taskie.ui.fragments.AboutAplicationFragment

class ViewPagerAdapter(manager :FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager) {


    companion object{
        const val NUM_OF_PAGES =2
        const val PAGE_ONE_TITLE = "About Application"
        const val PAGE_TWO_TITLE = "About Author"
    }

    private val frags = mutableListOf<Fragment>(AboutAplicationFragment(),AboutAplicationFragment())
    private val titles = mutableListOf(PAGE_ONE_TITLE, PAGE_TWO_TITLE)

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return frags[position]
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position :Int) : String{
        return titles[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return NUM_OF_PAGES
    }
}
```

Here is XML file with ViewPager and TabLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


  <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/viewPager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"
          />

  <TableLayout
          android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used `<TableLayout>` instead of `<TabLayout>`.